# How to check vimeo video is staff pick or not?

Tags: api, vimeo

How can I check the vimeo user video is a staff pick or not.

Example:
Name: Cristóbal Vila
URL: http://vimeo.com/eterea

He has 34 videos. In which one video is staff pick (video id= 57125220)
http://vimeo.com/57125220

How can we check the videos of a particular user is staffpick or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a verbose authenticated call to the `Vimeo.videos.getAll` method of the Vimeo Advanced API.

https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getAll/playground

This will return a user's videos, each one containing a flag of whether or not the video is a staff pick.